# How do you parse a dangling else?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler for the C- language and I only have one more problem to solve: how to handle the dangling else.  The original rule looks like:

> A --> if (expression) statement | if (expression) statement else statement

After getting rid of the left recursion:

> A --> if(expression) statement B
>
> B --> else statement | EMPTY

The problem is that "else" is in the first and follow sets of B.  I think this makes sense for an example like this:

```
if(x>y)
     if(x == 10)
          printf("x is 10.\n");
else
     printf("x<y");
```

The first if is followed by an else and the second if is followed by the same else, so there is ambiguity in how the rule was applied.  I get that I need to pair the else to the closest, open if, but I'm not sure how that translates into code for the parser.  When I hit rule A I'll call B, but then what?  If I see "else" as the next token, do I use B --> else statement or B --> EMPTY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parser is greedy. That is, a statement does not end until it *must* end. If something can be parsed as a continuation of the current, innermost statement, it is. So the inner `if` does not end when the `else` is encountered because it can include the following `else`, therefore it does.

When the parser encounters the `else`, it has two choices -- end the inner statement or don't end the inner statement. Such choices are always resolved in favor of making the statement as big as possible. Hence the term "greedy".

Comment: So I should always use B --> else statement and never B --> EMPTY if I see an "else" next?

Comment: Correct. Do not end a statement if it can continue.