# 'else' without previous 'if' error when defining macro with arguments

Tags: c, nested-if

Consider the C code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define foo(x) if (x>0) printf("Ouch\n");

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = -3;

    if(a>b)
        foo(b) ;
    else
        printf("Arrg!\n");
    printf("thanks\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When the program is run, I get an error saying `error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’`. When we replace `foo(b)` with `if (b>0) printf("Ouch\n")` according to the macro definition, shouldn't the program transfer into the following code when written with braces?

```
if(a>b){
    if(x>0){
        printf("Ouch\n");
    }
}
else{
    printf("Arrh!\n");
}
printf("thanks\n");
```

I don't see why the compiler complains. What does the program actually get transferred to?

Thanks

Comment: Most compilers have a flag to preprocess only. `gcc -E` for instance.

Comment: Related, but not quite duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592063/how-do-you-parse-a-dangling-else and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825259/why-is-there-a-dangling-else-scenario-here

Comment: Also of import if one wishes to address the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your macro expands to

```
if(a>b)
    if (b>0) printf("Ouch\n"); ; 
else 
    printf("Arrg!\n");
//...
```

and that won't work with the `else` because of the extra `;`. (Also you could have parenthesesized the `x` argument (`#define foo(x) if ((x)>0) printf("Ouch\n")`)).

If you lost the `;` from the macro, you'd get a different parse: the `else` would match up with the inner `if` like so:

```
if(a>b){ /*braces inserted to show the interpretation*/
    if (b>0) printf("Ouch\n");
    else printf("Arrg!\n");
}
```

and while you could solve the problem by making the macro with a dangling `else`

```
#define foo(x) if ((x)>0) printf("Ouch\n"); else
//a ; after the macro else would complete the `else` with an empty branch
```

using this, especially inside other `if`-`else` triggers warnings in compilers like `gcc`/`clang` when compiling `-Wall` and similar options, so the best way to deal with is with the idiomatic

```
#define macro() do{/*macro_body*/}while(0)
```

In your case

```
#define foo(x) do{ if ((x)>0) printf("Ouch\n"); }while(0)
```

Some people like to always use compound statements (surrounded by `{` `}`) with `if`/`else` statements, and while that would also solve the issue, I feel if you make function-like macros for other people to use, it's best not to force a style on them.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's turning into this code:

```
if (a > b)
        if (b > 0) printf("Ouch\n");;
    else
        printf("Arrg!\n");
```

Note that there are **two** semicolons after `("Ouch\n")`. This is what breaks the code. The `else` follows that second semicolon which is a null statement, not the `if` statement before that. The cause of this is that you have a semicolon in your macro definition and another one where you call the macro.

I suggest putting the statement(s) of a function-like macro in its own block, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55933720/10411602) suggests. But that's a generall suggestion, in this specific example it's best to not have a macro at all.

Comment: Technically, the replacement is `if (b > 0) printf("Ouch\n");;`. Furthermore you do not tell the OP how to correct this problem. Removing the trailing `;` as he may infer will cause another problem, much more difficult to spot.

Comment: @chqrlie oh wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the correction, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to ignore any suggestions on how to *fix* that macro, the *real* problem is that you're using the macro *at all.*

There is almost ***no*** reason to use macros (which are really just slightly-less-than-dumb text substitutions) in modern C for anything other than conditional compilation.

- Value-type macros should generally be replaced with enumerations because they better preserve type information.
- Function type macros should just *be* functions since modern compilers have very little trouble making them inline if they need it.

Using real functions also solves all those bizarre edge cases like:

```
#define calc(x) x * x
:
int a = 7;
int b = calc(a + 1);   // a + (1 * a) + 1, NOT (a + 1) * (a + 1)
```

If you want that to work reliably, you need the macro to be something like `((x) * (x))`, but even *that* will fail with more complexity, such as `b = calc(a++)`.

---

So, in short, what you *should* have in your code is:

```
void foo(int x) {
    if (x > 0)
        printf("Ouch\n");
}
```

---

If you *do* need to be able to use function macros *anywhere* (naked statement, statement within a braced if-block, statement within an unbraced if-block, braced and unbraced while statements and so on), you have to resort to bizarre macros such as (making sure to `#include <stdbool.h>` to get access to `false`, of course):

```
#define XYZZY(s) do {plugh(s);} while (false)
```

However, I would *strongly* suggest just making them functions in the first place.

Comment: I have run into one or two cases where a functional style macro was the best solution, but it is VERY rare. If you are using a macro, it's time for a code review.

Comment: Advice about how to *fix* the macro does teach the OP about macro traps and pitfalls. Your advice is superior, except for the use of `false` which may be undefined if the OP does not include `<stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Its always considered as safe and good practice to use `{ }` after `if` and `else` block to avoid such issues.

Correct one is

```
if(a>b) { 
    foo(b) ; /* keep inside { } */
}
else {
    printf("Arrg!\n");
}
```

> shouldn't the program transfer into the following code when written
>   with braces?

No, compiler doesn't put manually curly braces. After Macro replacement `gcc -E test.c` looks like

```
int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = -3;

    if(a>b)
        if (b>0) printf("Ouch\n"); ; /* extra semicolon causes the issue */
    else /* there is no if for this else block, previous one terminated by extra ; in above if */
        printf("Arrg!\n");
    printf("thanks\n");

    return 0;
}
```

sample code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define foo(x) if ((x)>0) printf("Ouch\n") /* if condition was wrong.. instead of x use (x) */
int main(void)
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = -3;
    if(a>b)
    { /* always keep curly braces even though there is only one statement after if */
        foo(b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Arrg!\n");
    }
    printf("thanks\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Though I would suggest to define MACRO like below

```
#define foo(x) \
    do {                   \
        if((x) > 0)         \
        printf("Ouch\n");  \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: This advice solves the symptoms, not the real issue. `#define foo(x) if (x>0) printf("Ouch\n");` is broken in multiple ways, curly braces will not save the OP from failing on `foo(b & 1)`